Google Assistant being extremely intrusive in my Django website
I have a homepage where the text - when clicked triggers Google Assistant to translate it, and this is very bad experience for the user.
I have tried to set the website language so GoogleAssistant don't just translate/define english words. and have tried the following snippets but in vain.
no-translate
<html lang="en">
What else possibly I can do this avoid this annoyment.
I expected to work "normally" but anytime a word or text is clicked Google Assistant gets into play.
GIF Description of the problem
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lt5AvTd6WXTkO5NyK-tPHPOPlMdva1rC

Clarify if the issue occurs on specific devices or browsers. Provide more context on how Google Assistant is triggered.

That's not a translation box, that's the search overlay.
I'd suggest adding user-select: none to your navigation bar, so people can't accidentally select the text (as selecting text triggers the search overlay).
